# AVAssetExportSession giving me a green border on right and bottom of output video

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition, avasset

Here's the code:

```
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
        exporter.outputURL = outputUrl;
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
        exporter.videoComposition = mainComposition;
        exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
        [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            //completion
        }];
```

I've tried different quality settings. I always get a 1-2 pixel border running down the right side of the video and along the bottom, no matter what video I'm trying to render. What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

EDIT: I am not using any kind of green color anywhere, so this must be coming from the framework somehow.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Usually green lines appear after video cropping, problem is in video renderSize width, it should be multiply of 16.

Here some links about this:
[apple 1](https://discussions.apple.com/message/12874240#12874240)
[apple 2](https://discussions.apple.com/message/8525272#8525272)

Comment: For me just making sure the video had an even width did the trick (the number I tested wasn't a multiple of 4, 8 or 16)

Answer (score 19):

a much nicer solution to get the multiple of 16 would be this approach:

```
floor(width / 16) * 16
```

or

```
ceil(width / 16) * 16
```

depending on your preference of having a smaller or bigger width

Answer (score 6):

This did the magic for me (iOS9, Swift 3, iPhone 6):

Based on:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/94404/play-record-merge-videos-ios-swift

Changing **mainComposition.renderSize** to:

```
mainComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: self.mainCompositionWidth, height: self.mainCompositionHeight)
```

where **mainCompositionWidth**, **mainCompositionHeight** are **CGFloat**s and are calculated like this:

```
 self.mainCompositionWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    self.mainCompositionHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height

    while (self.mainCompositionWidth%16>0) { // find the right resolution that can be divided by 16
        self.mainCompositionWidth = self.mainCompositionWidth + 1.0
    }

    while (self.mainCompositionHeight%16>0) { // find the right resolution that can be divided by 16
        self.mainCompositionHeight = self.mainCompositionHeight + 1.0
    }
```

Also modifying **scaleFitRatio** in the **videoCompositionInstructionForTrack** function to:

```
scaleToFitRatio = self.mainCompositionWidth / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
```

This made the bottom green line disappear and the video fills the screen.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that if AVMutableVideoComposition's render size width isn't an even number, you get the mysterious green borders. Good times.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the proper resolution try something like this... increment it until the nearest number that can be divided by 16:

```
computedVideoSize=self.view.frame.size.width;

while (computedVideoSize%16>0) { // find the right resolution that can be divided by 16
    computedVideoSize++;
}
```